# slicing StandardScaler for unrolled time steps

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, standardized

Here's a simplified explanation: I have a dataframe of multiple unrolled time-steps that is used to predict price2 and volume2 (the next step). Before I train my network, I want to use [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

However, when I went to invert the predicted that data, I now have the challenge that the StandardScaler is adjusted to lenght of 4 and hence cannot be applied to my output length of 2.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':10, 'price1':20, 'volume':100, 'volume1':75})
```

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: StandardScaler is used only for the normalization of the data. What do you want to do exactly? Can you add the full code and data ?

Comment: Are you sure you are standardizing the way you wish?  StandardScaler will scale per column by default, but it sounds like you want it to scale per series.